# Cache Static Contents in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

Is there any suitable way for caching in HAProxy. I want to cache only the static files (css, js, images). So, my initial plan was to do something like below

```
backend app_backend
    mode http
    balance source
    option httpchk GET /heartbeat
    http-check expect status 200
    http-request cache-use mycache if { path -i -m beg /html/ } || { path -i -m beg /css/ } || { path -i -m beg /favicon.ico } || { path -i -m beg /assets/ } || { path -i -m beg /images/ } || { path -i -m beg /js/ }
    http-response cache-store mycache
    option httpclose
```

But I don't see anything is getting cached in my Proxy server.
What am I doing wrong?